# Center a TextView in a TableRow in a TableLayout

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to build something like a header. I tried using `android:gravity="center"` and `android:textAlignment="center"` on the TextView but it doesn't center the text. I don't know where the problem is.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#008000" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/HeaderTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        <!--android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"-->
        android:text="@string/header"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Provide android:gravity="center" in TableRow

Comment: Just for the sake of future planning, is this the advisable way if I want to put a button on the left and the right of the TextView?

Comment: For that,you can add RelativeLayout inside your TableRow.

Comment: Nice! It cancelled the centering but I managed to figure that out.

Comment: Could you post the full code that works ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#008000" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/HeaderTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="header"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 18):

give **android:gravity="center"** to `TableRow`.

Comment: Works like charm! this piece of `code` ate 3hrs of my life time :D

Comment: This even works for views inside of a TableRow, whereas 
   `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` did not for me.

Answer (score 2):

Set gravity to table row

```
<TableLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <TableRow 
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have many `TextView` inside `TableRow` doing this solved my problem

```
    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:text="@string/feedback" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:text="@string/football" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:text="@string/about" />

        </TableRow>
```